# Segmentation Fault 11 error in C program where I would have to count occurrences of words entered

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, structure, self-reference

My program is from the C programming language book from K&R on section 6.5 where we are investigating self referential structures. Here, we would have to count the number of occurrences of words inputted into the terminal. We would have to construct a binary tree of words and keep track of the count. I am getting a segmentation Fault 11 error in the addtree function. I think p  in that function is not pointing to the correct memory. But I am not sure how to fix it. Here is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXWORD 100
#define BUFSIZE 100

struct tnode{
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct tnode *left; //left child. referential way of declaring
    struct tnode *right;
};

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *, char *);
void treeprint(struct tnode *);
int get_word(char *, int);
struct tnode *talloc(void);
char *my_strdup(char *);

int main(){
    struct tnode *root;
    char word[MAXWORD];
    while(get_word(word, MAXWORD) != EOF){
        if(isalpha(word[0])){
            printf("Still in main going in addtree function\n");
            root = addtree(root, word);
        }
    }
    treeprint(root);
    return 0;
}

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w){
    int cond;
    printf("Inside addtree function.\n");

    if(p == NULL){ //a new word has arrived
        p = talloc();
        p->word = my_strdup(w);
        p->count = 1;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    }else if((cond = strcmp(p->word, w))==0)
        p->count++;
    else if(cond < 0)
        p->right = addtree(p->right, w);
    else
        p->left = addtree(p->left, w);
    return p;
}

void treeprint(struct tnode *p){
    if(p!=NULL){
        printf("Coming inside treeprint statement.\n");
        treeprint(p->left);
        printf("%4d    %s\n", p->count, p->word);
        treeprint(p->right);
    }
}

struct tnode *talloc(void){
    return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

char *my_strdup(char *w){
    char *p;
    p = (char *) malloc(strlen(w)+1);
    if(p!=NULL)
        strcpy(p, w);
    return p;
}

char buf[BUFSIZE]; //buffer for ungetch
int bufp = 0; //next free position in buf

int getch(void){
    return (bufp>0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c){
    if(bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters.\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}

//get next word or character from input
int get_word(char *word, int lim){
    int c;
    int getch(void);
    void ungetch(int);
    char *w = word;
    while((isspace(c = getch())))
        ;
    if(c != EOF){
        *w++ = c;
    }
    printf("c: %d\n", c);
    printf("\n*w: %c", *w);
    if(!isalpha(c)){
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    for( ; --lim > 0; w++){
        if(!isalnum(*w = getch())){
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    }
    *w = '\0';
    printf("word[0]: %c\n", word[0]);
    return word[0];
}
```

Comment: You did not initialized the variable roort struct tnode *root;

Comment: It's not guaranteed that in `treeprint(root);`, `root` has been initialized.

Comment: It is already initialized as struct node *p in the function. I am not understanding what you are trying to imply. Would you please show write the correct line of code which I should be running.

Comment: @RidwanChowdhury, the body of an `if`statement is only executed if the condition is met, if you are saying the condition is always true then there is no point having it, in the future if you want answers you must tag the poster otherwise he will not be notified.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing here:

```
}else if((cond = strcmp(p->word, w))==0)
```

on the first run, because root->word was never allocated/initialized.

I would strongly suggest, as you work your way through learning C, that you also learn to use a C debugger. [Here is a great gdb tutorial](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/). With a debugger, you will find the source problems like this almost instantly.

Here's what gdb output looks like if you try to run this program, for example:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/nick/a.out 
hello darkness my old friend #<-- my keyboard input
c: 104

*w: ?word[0]: h
Still in main going in addtree function
Inside addtree function.

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
addtree (p=0x23792ac296e9f5c5, w=0x7f7fffff1680 "hello") at test.c:44
44      }else if((cond = strcmp(p->word, w))==0)
Current language:  auto; currently minimal
```

Comment: Before writing your answer it is sometimes useful to read comments to the question.

Comment: It is already initialized as struct node *p in the function. I am not understanding what you are trying to imply. Would you please show write the correct line of code which I should be running.